# Limits of sequences and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm currently learning about the limits of a sequence based on the following definition:

A sequence $x_n$ is said to converge to $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if for every $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $ n \geq K$, $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$

I'm working through the following exercise:

Show that:

$$\lim \left(\frac{(-1)^{n}n}{n^2+1}\right) = 0$$

I'm pretty confused about how to approach this problem.

Could someone give me a hint on how to start?

Also, is there a general way to approach these types of problem?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Note that

$$\left|\frac{(-1)^nn}{n^2+1}\right|=\frac{n}{n^2+1}<\frac{n}{n^2}\;.$$

There are some ideas that come up often, and with practice you’ll come to recognize them, but in general you have to attack such problems individually.

Comment: I was extremely confused about what to do with $(-1)^n$ and I apparently completely ignored the absolute value. Thanks! 

A follow-up question: 
Could you help me understand the definition that I posted?
I'm not sure how it shows that a sequence converges to the supposed x.

Comment: @Alex: Think of $\epsilon$ as setting an allowable margin of error: you want to get your terms within $\epsilon$ of the exact target $x$. The condition in the definition says that no matter how small a margin of error you allow, **every** term of the sequence from some point on is within that margin. Alternatively, if you define $T_n=\{x_k:k\ge n\}$, the $n$-th ‘tail’ of the sequence, you’re saying that no matter how small a margin you allow, some whole tail fits entirely inside it (and of course so does every later tail). Intuitively this says that not only does the sequence have terms ...

Comment: ... arbitrarily close to $x$, but if you go far enough out you can get **all** terms from that point on within a given margin of error.

Comment: Also note that the following are all equivalent: $a_n \to 0$, $-a_n \to 0$, and $|a_n| \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:$$\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}=\dfrac{1}{n+\dfrac1n}\to 0\,\,\,\,\, \text{as}\,\,\,\,\,n\to\infty$$

Comment: @Nilan , where abouts in Sri Lanka? what are you studying now?

Comment: Yes. I am a Srilankan and I was studied at uni. of Peradeniya. How about you?

Comment: I did maths special at university of Colombo.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{-1}{n} < \frac{-n}{n^2+1} \leq \frac{(-1)^n n}{n^2 +1} \leq \frac{n}{n^2+1} < \frac{1}{n}$. The outer two sequences both converge to $0$, it follows from the sandwich theorem that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(-1)^n n}{n^2 + 1} = 0$, too.